# MongoDB : Mongoid and I18n translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am going to start a new project based on the top of MongoDB.

My application will need to handle fields translations.

I discovered a plugin named : [Mongoid_i18n](https://github.com/Papipo/mongoid_i18n)

Is it the only one plugin interesting ? Or other plugins are available ?

Comment: Take a look at the [Translator](https://github.com/amberbit/translator) gem from Hubert Łępicki / amerbit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoid >= 2.4 includes this facility natively.  See: http://two.mongoid.org/docs/documents/localized.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that'd be the one. You could do it yourself as well which might be a little easier depending on how localizable your field names are.

-Roger